# How to retrieve/use nonce using login.live oauth2.0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal, xbox-live

I'm trying to create a webapp to authentify Xbox users on my service by using `login.live.com` and I want to use a nonce like in the msal java code example provided in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-java).

In their example, they redirect the user to `login.microsoftonline.com` to retrieve an access code and request provide a nonce generated on the server which is also accepted when adding it in the `login.live.com` redirection. The problem comes when retrieving an access token on the server side which is normally in a `JWT` format holding the nonce which is true when using `login.microsoftonline.com`.

In the current situation my request for the access is a `POST` request with the url: `https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf` and with header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and body:

```
{
    "client_id": MY_CLIENT_ID,
    "client_secret": MY_SECRET,
    "code": access_code
    "grant_type": authorization_code
    "redirect_uri": https//localhost:8443/auth/callback
}
```

and as answer I receive something like bellow where I cannot parse the `"access_token"` using `JWT` to retrieve a nonce:

```
{
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "scope": "XboxLive.signin XboxLive.offline_access",
  "access_token": "EwAwA+pvBA...",
  "refresh_token": "M.R3_BL2.-...",
  "user_id": "AA.."
}
```

So, if I'm missing anything like if I need to use specific scopes, if it just not possible or there are other ways to do it, please help

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment
`https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=c46xxxx50cf6b692038&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:xxx/auth/callback`

But only got nonce parameter when `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token` is given as endpoint.

Also , try giving random nonce value `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantName>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<appID_of_your_client_application>&nonce=anyRandomValue&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri_of_your_client_application>&scope=<your scope>&response_type=code`

- Then redirect url can be given for native client as https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf

[image]

Then nonce parameter can be seen in token

[image]